# Send multiple CURL posts

Tags: php, curl

I need to post 3+ different urls at the same time. The function below posts to 2 at the same time, but not sure how to get it to 3+ -- been trying to figure it out, what am I missing? Do i have to do it a different way? Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

```
<?php 

    $data7 = array(
    "F9domain" => $f9d,
    "F9list" => 'LIVE LIST -  UN - AUG15',
    "first_name" => $fn1,
    "last_name" => $fn2,
    "Email" => $email,
    "number1" => $phone,
    "street" => $address,
    "city" => $city,
    "state" => $state,
    "zip" => $zip,
    "IPAddress" => $ip,
    );




    function post_to_url($url, $data) {
    $fields = '';   
    foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
      $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
    }
    rtrim($fields, '&');

    $post = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);


    $result = curl_exec($post);

    curl_close($post);
    }






//sales@sentsmart
post_to_url("http://url1", $data3);

//BlueFire Media
post_to_url("http://url2", $data6);

//five9
post_to_url("url3", $data7);



?>
```

Comment: And how do you know it didn't work for the third URL?